# How can i show image field inside my RentListAPIView?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-1.9

I have two models rental and gallery. My models look like this

**Models.py**(shortened with less fields)

```
class Rental(models.Model):
    ownerName = models.CharField(_("Owner's Name"),max_length=255, blank=True,null=True,
        help_text=_("Owner's Full Name"))
    renter = models.ForeignKey(User,null=True,blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=120,blank=True,null=True)
    phoneNumber = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False,null=True,
        help_text=_("Phone number of contact person"))
    listingName =  models.CharField(_("Lisitng Name"), max_length=255, blank=False,null=True,
        help_text=_("Title of the rental space"))


class Gallery(models.Model):
    rental = models.ForeignKey('Rental', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name=_('Rental'), related_name="gallery")
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True,upload_to='upload/',null=True)
```

**Serializers.py**

```
class RentalListSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    renter = SerializerMethodField()
    # gallery = GalleryListSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Rental

    def get_renter(self, obj):
        return str(obj.renter.username)

class GalleryListSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Gallery
```

**Views.py**

```
class RentalListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    # queryset = Rental.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RentalListSerializer
    filter_backends = [SearchFilter]
    search_fields = ['place','city']
    pagination_class = RentalPageNumberPagination

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # queryset_list = super(RentalListAPIView,self).get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
        queryset_list = Rental.objects.all()
        query = self.request.GET.get('q') # this is a class based view so we need to use self 
        if query:
            queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(
                Q(place__icontains=query)|
                Q(city__icontains=query)
                ).distinct()
        return queryset_list


    class GalleryListAPIView(ListAPIView):
        # queryset = Rental.objects.all()
        serializer_class = GalleryListSerializer
        pagination_class = RentalPageNumberPagination

        def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
            queryset_list = Gallery.objects.all()
            return queryset_list
```

MY API design looks like this

[image]

But i need image field too and each rent has multiple images  like this

[image]

Comment: Is just adding `gallery = GalleryListSerializer()` is not working?

Comment: I tried that. It says GalleryListSerializer not defined. When i shift GalleryListSerializer class from bottom to the top of RentListSerializer then i get error of AttributeError at /api/rentals/
'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'rental'

Comment: Please have a look at my answer. and you do need to move it from bottom to top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Nested Relationships](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships) in django rest framework.

> If the field is used to represent a `to-many` relationship, you should add the `many=True` flag to the serializer field.

What you have right now is this, which I think is not working and that's why you have it commented.:

```
# gallery = GalleryListSerializer()
```

What you need is following:

```
gallery = GalleryListSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
```

Comment: Dont i have to move it from bottom to top?

Comment: Yes you do need to do that.

Comment: Ok i will try that and let you know

Comment: yes it worked but how using many=True resolved the issue of ttributeError at /api/rentals/ 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'rental'

Comment: Sorry i did not see the updated answer of yours. Dont mind with my previous comment.Thanks for the help. I will look at it.